# How does the XCode-Run-Command look like?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, xcodebuild, calabash

For an automatic testing purpose, I have to build & run a XCode Project. Right now i prepare my project using scripts, then I open XCode, chose the right scheme and click the run-button. Afterwards I run my test script. All works fine!

I have to eliminate the manual steps (open XCode, run Project) and use scripts as well. Until now I did not yet figure out how to build and run my project exactly the same way as XCode does. I tried with the commands xcodebuild, xcrun simctl, ios-sim and all kind of parameters.

How can I fire the exact same command in the terminal? Thanks!

### Edited

I reference to this question https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/issues/1076, which is the root of this question.

I tried again using both the "Debug Config" and the "-cal target" approach (https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Tutorial%3A-How-to-add-Calabash-to-Xcode). Both possibilities work perfect if I do a manual build in Xcode. I studied jmoodys Examples and tried the following (I changed it a bit cause of the nature of my Ionic project):

```
xcrun xcodebuild  \
    TARGET_BUILD_DIR=\$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR \
    DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH=\$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR \
    -xcconfig cordova/build-debug.xcconfig \
    -project './ABC.xcodeproj' \
    -scheme 'ABC-cal' \
    -configuration Debug \
    -sdk iphonesimulator \
    -SYMROOT="build/app" \
    ARCHS="i386 x86_64" \
    VALID_ARCHS="i386 x86_64" \
    ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO \
    build
```

The build runs without any error, creates the app at the exact same location as the xcode build and cucumber runs and opens the app, BUT the steps are never executed and I dont get any error. I guess my build is still not exact the same?

Comment: Where exactly do you get stuck? With xcodebuild you can specify the scheme and the build configuration and so on.

Comment: I know that there are many options. My problem is that I tried different things and don't get the same result. That's why im wondering what exactly the run-command does, or in other words how i can run it the same way in the console? (I try to compile an Ionic project and run calabash-test with cucumber, there I get a "Expected 'x86_64' but found ["armv7", "arm64"]"-Exception)

Comment: After reading this several times, I am confused about what the problem is.  Are you complaining because the build script puts the .app into the DerivedData directory?  Or do you want the .app (and all the build products) built to a local directory?  Or is the build script working as expected, but cucumber is not executing?  You an error from running cucumber in your comment, is that what this question is really about?

Comment: The only problem I have, is that Cucumber does not execute the test steps after it started the app. Obviously this is related to the xcodebuild, BECAUSE if I build it with XCode the test executes.

Answer (score 1):

There are example scripts in these repositories:

- [Permissions](https://github.com/calabash/Permissions)
- [CalSmokeApp](https://github.com/calabash/ios-smoke-test-app/tree/master/CalSmokeApp/bin/make)
- [CalWebApp](https://github.com/calabash/ios-webview-test-app/tree/master/CalWebViewApp/bin/make)
- [iPhoneOnlyApp](https://github.com/calabash/ios-iphone-only-app)

The Permissions repo is the easiest to understand.  You can probably just grab the `bin/make/app.sh` and `bin/make/ipa.sh` and update a couple of environment variables.

I can't be sure, but I think you posted this *exact* question as an [issue on Calabash iOS](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/issues/1076).   If so, please don't cross post.  I answered your question there, provided the same examples, and asked you follow up questions that you did not respond to.

Comment: Many thanks jmoody. It was not my goal to cross post, I just thought that this is a more fundamental question and is not directly related to calabash (github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/issues/1076). I edited my initial questions after a long day of trying.